# Wix CheckBox default state

Tags: wix, windows-installer

The dialog below displays a checkbox which on selected enables the Next Button. The problem is I cant get the initial state of it to be set to unchecked when the form first appears. I have tried setting the CheckBoxValue = 1 but that doesnt either work.

```
    <Dialog Id="DatabaseDialog" X="50" Y="50" Width="373" Height="287" Title="[ProductName]">
                <Control Id="EnableCheckBox" Property="DatabaseBackedUp" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="150" Width="290" Height="30" 
                         Text="Has the database been backed up?" CheckBoxValue="0" />
                <Control Id="NextButton" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="261" Width="66" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}&amp;Next &gt;" TabSkip="no" Default="yes">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">DatabaseDialog_NextArgs=""</Publish>
                    <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="[DatabaseDialog_NextArgs]">DatabaseDialog_NextArgs&lt;&gt;""</Publish>
                 <Condition Action="disable"><![CDATA[DatabaseBackedUp<> "1"]]></Condition>
                 <Condition Action="enable"><![CDATA[DatabaseBackedUp= "1"]></Condition>
                </Control>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the way I do it and it works for me

The Property:

```
  <Property Id="CHECKBOX" Secure="yes"></Property>
```

The checkbox:

```
<Control Id="CheckBoxId" Type="CheckBox"  Text="Use the proxy server for your LAN" Property="CHECKBOX" Width="180" Height="15" X="25" Y="103" CheckBoxValue="1"/>
```

I believe this works because you are firstly setting the property linked to the checkbox to nothing so it stays empty and if it is clicked then the property value is equal to whatever the `CheckBoxValue` is set to. (That's my logic anyway..:)) Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I have a property defined but obscurely set it to an arbitrary value.

Comment: While this may work, I feel it is a workaround. I know if you do not set the `Secure` attribute on `Property`, then you will get a build warning `"Property 'CHECKBOX' does not contain a Value attribute and is not marked as Admin, Secure, or Hidden. The Property element is being ignored."` Setting the `Secure` attribute does make this warning go away, but it has its own functionality that may or may not be desired (specifically, that the Property can be passed to the server side when performing a managed installation with elevated privileges).

Answer (score 5):

You have defined a control:

```
<Control Id="EnableCheckBox"
         Type="CheckBox"
         Property="DatabaseBackedUp" 
         X="20" Y="150" Width="290" Height="30" 
         Text="Has the database been backed up?" 
         CheckBoxValue="0" />
```

You don't mention whether you have also defined a `DatabaseBackedUp` property elsewhere in your solution, but I assume that you have defined something like this:

```
<Property Id="DatabaseBackedUp" Value="0"></Property>
```

You may have tried other values for `Value`. However, I believe the checkbox will interpret the existence of *any* value as meaning "I should be checked".

However, if you do not set a `Value` attribute then you will get a warning: `"Property 'CHECKBOX' does not contain a Value attribute and is not marked as Admin, Secure, or Hidden. The Property element is being ignored."`

Setting one of these attributes will make the warning go away, but will come with additional behaviour that may or may not be desired.

**The solution is simply to delete the property**.

The checkbox will then find no value for it and will default to unchecked. Checking it will still work as desired (i.e. it will create and set a value for the property).

I have tried this successfully with WiX v3.11.1.